# Aussi clairement que

Tags: expressions, conjonctions, comparatifs

> Je me rappelle l'événement **aussi clairement que** s'il avait eu lieu
> hier.
>
> Je me souviens de ta voix **aussi clairement que** si tu étais encore ici.

([lien](https://gikken.co/mate-translate/sentences/french/clairement))

Quelqu'un m'a dit que cette construction dans des phrases semblables est incorrecte. Est-ce vrai ? À mon avis, ces phrases sont correctes. Il est possible de reformuler :

> Je me rappelle l'événement très clairement, **comme s**'il avait eu lieu
> hier.
>
> Je me souviens de ta voix clairement, **comme si** tu étais encore ici.

Mais selon moi, les phrases initiales sont correctes...

Answer (score 2):

« Aussi clairement que si » a récemment été beaucoup utilisé. L'élément hypothétique de comparaison peut être n'importe quoi, ce que montre les nombreux exemples sur cette [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22aussi%20clairement%20que%20si%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr).

[image]

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aussi+clairement+que+si&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caussi%20clairement%20que%20si%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caussi%20clairement%20que%20si%3B%2Cc0)

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_Romance_de_T%C3%A9n%C3%A9breuse_tome_3/LPd_jX7DLyMC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22aussi+clairement+que+si%22&pg=PT11&printsec=frontcover)) Se ravisant, elle s'interrompit,mais, avec son don nouvellement éveillé, Romilly l'entendit aussi clairement que si elle avait parlé tout haut.

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_politique_%C3%A9trang%C3%A8re_de_la_France/kpx1QBA43eMC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22aussi+clairement+que+si%22&dq=%22aussi+clairement+que+si%22&printsec=frontcover)) Et quand il y un geste criminel , nous le démontrerons aussi clairement que si M. Gromyko ne devait pas venir quelques jours plus tard en France ou que si nous ne cherchions pas à confirmer l'amélioration de notre balance commerciale ...

Noter que les temps du subjonctif peuvent être utilisés dans la langue littéraire à la place de l'imparfait et du plus que parfait de l'indicatif.

- Je me rappelle l'événement très clairement, comme s'il eût eu lieu hier.
- Je me souviens de ta voix clairement, comme si tu fusses encore ici.

Answer (score 1):

Les phrases avec *clairement* ne me paraissent pas naturelles.

*Clairement* pourrait être utilisé comme ceci :

> Je t'entends aussi clairement que si tu étais à côté de moi.

La forme largement la plus courante pour se référer à un événement est :

> Je m'en souviens comme si c'était hier.

Pour la voix, c'est un peu plus complexe car une voix n'est généralement pas associée à une date.

> Je me souviens de ta voix comme si je venais de te parler.

Comment: Tu voulais dire _aussi clairement qu**e** si tu étais à côté de moi_ ? Mais en quoi la phrase _Je t'entends aussi clairement que si tu étais à côté de moi_ diffère des phrases initiales ? C'est la même structure.

Comment: La structure est correcte. C'est juste que la combinaison *se rappeller* et *clairement* me semble un peu inhabituelle.  *Je m'en rappelle un peu/bien/très bien/parfaitement*  sont ce à quoi je m'attendrais.